# DropdownList not populating from Database

Tags: asp.net, code-behind

I have an unbound Dropdownlist in my asp content page with the following code behind

```
 using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection  
      (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ToString()))
         {

            try
            {


      SqlDataAdapter myDAMgr = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT  UserId from  
      dbo.LoanOwnerStampManager ", myConnection);

                myDAMgr.Fill(Manager);

                ddlManagerName.DataTextField = "UserId";
                ddlManagerName.DataValueField = "UserId";
                ddlManagerName.DataBind();
            }  // end try


            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex = ex.InnerException;


            }

            finally
            {
                myConnection.Dispose();
            }
         ddlManagerName.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", "0"));  // this  is   the Initial Value for the dropdownlist.
        } // end Using
```

Now in my ASP PAGE , NOTHING special

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblManager" Text ="Manager's Name" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" 
  style="margin-right: 10px"
    ForeColor="#003366" ></asp:Label>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlManagerName"  runat="server" Height="22px" 
    style="margin-left: 6px" Width="128px"></asp:DropDownList>
```

But the Dropdown list never gets populated !! Hope for another pair of eyes to figure out the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never set the `DataSource` for the drop down.

I am assuming you want to bind to `Manager` (the DataSet you fill), like this:

```
ddlManagerName.DataSource = Manager;
```

Comment: No problem, we have all been there. Sometimes, like you said, a fresh pair of eyes makes all the difference in the world. If you feel my answer helped you, then feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to open connection.

```
 using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection  
      (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ToString()))
         {

            try
            {
              myConnection.Open();
              Your code as it was
```

Also

```
ddlManager.DataSource = Manager;

ddlManager.DataValueField= "ValueColumnOfDataTable";
ddlManager.DataTextFiedl="TextColumn";
ddlManager.DataBind();
ddlManager.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Select---","-1"));
```

Comment: Thanks, I had the connection open elsewhere. But i guess i should bring it into try as proper code standards.